# sqlite3 doesn't insert rows in the loop

Tags: python, sqlite

Cannot make this work. print outputs all three items' details parsed from xml response, but inserts into db just a first one. Thanks in advance

```
  conn = sqlite3.connect('phones.db')
  c = conn.cursor()

  ...

  else: 
  CmNodes = resp.SelectCmDeviceResult.CmNodes.item
  for CmNodes in CmNodes:
        if len(CmNodes) > 0:
            for item in CmNodes.CmDevices.item:
                print(item.Name, item.Status, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item.TimeStamp)
                c.execute('INSERT INTO phones VALUES (?,?)', (item.Name, datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item.TimeStamp)))
    c.execute('SELECT * FROM phones')
    print(c.fetchone())
    conn.commit()
    c.close()
```

Output:

```
CSFVSAVOSTI Registered 2020-07-12 07:52:30
SEPC40ACB4C5A48 Registered 2020-07-11 18:25:53
SEP084FA90D1D46 Registered 2020-07-11 18:23:52
('CSFVSAVOSTI', '2020-07-12 07:52:30')
Execution completed
```

Comment: The inserted items will be visible after `conn.commit()`. So try doing the select after that.

Comment: also you're doing `fetchone()` which will fetch just the first row anyway so I'm not sure what you were expecting to happen there

Comment: you actually helped. Thank you, that was really silly